# Swatches price update in catalog

Tags: magento2, swatches

i'm trying to update price when i change swatches in catalog.

I find this solution :

from https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3150

`app/design/CUSTOM/THEME/Magento_Swatches/templates/product/listing/renderer.phtml`

```
require(["jquery", "jquery/ui", "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer"], function ($) {         
        $('.swatch-opt-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProduct()->getId() ?>').SwatchRenderer({
            selectorProduct: '.product-item-details',
            onlySwatches: true,
            enableControlLabel: false,
            numberToShow: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getNumberSwatchesPerProduct(); ?>,
            jsonConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>,
            jsonSwatchConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonSwatchConfig(); ?>,
            mediaCallback: '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMediaCallback() ?>'
        });
    });
```

to

```
require(["jquery", "jquery/ui","priceBox", "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer"], function ($) {
         var dataPriceBoxSelector = '[data-role=priceBox]',
            dataProductIdSelector = '[data-product-id=<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getId()?>]',
            priceBoxes = $(dataPriceBoxSelector + dataProductIdSelector);

        priceBoxes = priceBoxes.filter(function(index, elem){
            return !$(elem).find('.price-from').length;
        });

        priceBoxes.priceBox();
        $('.swatch-opt-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProduct()->getId() ?>').SwatchRenderer({
            selectorProduct: '.product-item-details',
            onlySwatches: true,
            enableControlLabel: false,
            numberToShow: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getNumberSwatchesPerProduct(); ?>,
            jsonConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>,
            jsonSwatchConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonSwatchConfig(); ?>,
            mediaCallback: '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMediaCallback() ?>'
        });
    });
```

But as you can read in the post, it don't update price. So hopefully someone find how to do it :

> Your solutions works @johnny-longneck. For the price format this is
>   what I did:
>
> Instead of initializing the priceBox object on template file like:
>
> priceBoxes.priceBox();
>
> Pass the priceBox object as a parameter for SwatchRenderer
>
> priceBox: priceBoxes
>
> Then add the option to yout swatch-render.js constructor:
>
> priceBox: false,
>
> And then just initialize the priceBox at the beginning of the
>   _UpdatePrice method:
>
> var $widget = this; $widget.options.priceBox.priceBox();
>
> Hope it helps to someone !!

Ok, i try to do it but it don't work. Can someone sho me where exactly put this code ? thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Steps for update price:-

> app/design/CUSTOM/THEME/Magento_Swatches/templates/product/listing/renderer.phtml

```
require(["jquery", "jquery/ui","priceBox", "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer"], function ($) {
         var dataPriceBoxSelector = '[data-role=priceBox]',
                dataProductIdSelector = '[data-product-id=<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getId() ?>]',
                priceBoxes = $(dataPriceBoxSelector + dataProductIdSelector);



    priceBoxes = priceBoxes.filter(function (index, elem) {
        return !$(elem).find('.price-from').length;
    });
    priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfigPrice(); ?>});
    $('.swatch-opt-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProduct()->getId() ?>').SwatchRenderer({
        selectorProduct: '.product-item-details',
        onlySwatches: true,
        enableControlLabel: false,
        numberToShow: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getNumberSwatchesPerProduct(); ?>,
        jsonConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>,
        jsonSwatchConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonSwatchConfig(); ?>,
        mediaCallback: '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMediaCallback() ?>'
    });
});
```

and overrite

> Magento/Swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Listing/Configurable.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace [Namespace]\[Vendor]\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product as CatalogProduct;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer;
use Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data as SwatchData;
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media;
use Magento\Swatches\Model\Swatch;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Swatches\Model\SwatchAttributesProvider;
/**
 * Swatch renderer block in Category page
 *
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Configurable extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable
{
        /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface
     */


protected $_localeFormat;

protected $_jsonEncoder;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
    EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    Data $helper,
    CatalogProduct $catalogProduct,
    CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
    PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    ConfigurableAttributeData $configurableAttributeData,
    SwatchData $swatchHelper,
    Media $swatchMediaHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    array $data = [],
    SwatchAttributesProvider $swatchAttributesProvider = null
) {
    $this->_localeFormat = $localeFormat;
    $this->_jsonEncoder =  $jsonEncoder;
    $this->swatchHelper = $swatchHelper;
    $this->swatchMediaHelper = $swatchMediaHelper;
    $this->swatchAttributesProvider = $swatchAttributesProvider
        ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SwatchAttributesProvider::class);
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $arrayUtils,
        $jsonEncoder,
        $helper,
        $catalogProduct,
        $currentCustomer,
        $priceCurrency,
        $configurableAttributeData,
        $swatchHelper,
        $swatchMediaHelper,
        $data,
        $swatchAttributesProvider
    );
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
protected function getRendererTemplate()
{
    return $this->_template;
}

/**
 * Produce and return block's html output.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $output = '';
    if ($this->isProductHasSwatchAttribute()) {
        $output = parent::_toHtml();
    }

    return $output;
}

/**
 * @deprecated
 * @return string
 */
protected function getHtmlOutput()
{
    $output = '';
    if ($this->isProductHasSwatchAttribute()) {
        $output = parent::getHtmlOutput();
    }

    return $output;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
protected function getSwatchAttributesData()
{
    $result = [];
    $swatchAttributeData = parent::getSwatchAttributesData();
    foreach ($swatchAttributeData as $attributeId => $item) {
        if (!empty($item['used_in_product_listing'])) {
            $result[$attributeId] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

/**
 * Composes configuration for js
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getJsonConfig()
{
    $this->unsetData('allow_products');
    return parent::getJsonConfig();
}


  /**
 * Get JSON encoded configuration array which can be used for JS dynamic
 * price calculation depending on product options
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getJsonConfigPrice()
{
    /* @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */
    $product = $this->getProduct();

    if (!$this->hasOptions()) {
        $config = [
            'productId' => $product->getId(),
            'priceFormat' => $this->_localeFormat->getPriceFormat()
            ];
        return $this->_jsonEncoder->encode($config);
    }

    $tierPrices = [];
    $tierPricesList = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('tier_price')->getTierPriceList();
    foreach ($tierPricesList as $tierPrice) {
        $tierPrices[] = $this->priceCurrency->convert($tierPrice['price']->getValue());
    }
    $config = [
        'productId' => $product->getId(),
        'priceFormat' => $this->_localeFormat->getPriceFormat(),
        'prices' => [
            'oldPrice' => [
                'amount' => $this->priceCurrency->convert(
                    $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue()
                ),
                'adjustments' => []
            ],
            'basePrice' => [
                'amount' => $this->priceCurrency->convert(
                    $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getBaseAmount()
                ),
                'adjustments' => []
            ],
            'finalPrice' => [
                'amount' => $this->priceCurrency->convert(
                    $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue()
                ),
                'adjustments' => []
            ]
        ],
        'idSuffix' => '_clone',
        'tierPrices' => $tierPrices
    ];

    $responseObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_product_view_config', ['response_object' => $responseObject]);
    if (is_array($responseObject->getAdditionalOptions())) {
        foreach ($responseObject->getAdditionalOptions() as $option => $value) {
            $config[$option] = $value;
        }
    }



    return $this->_jsonEncoder->encode($config);
    }
}
```